Latex errors when the number of nodes of a graph is more than 26!
I do not need any counter, I am just trying to draw a graph with 35 nodes. However, it gives the following errors: counter too large!  and  missing \endcsname inserted!
The problem, I guess, is because of the number of nodes is greater than 26 since when I change the number of nodes less than 27 the code works. Do you have any idea?
Here is the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amscd,latexsym}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsfonts}


\begin{document}

\SetGraphUnit{2}

  \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple]

  \SetVertexSimple[MinSize = 0.5pt, LineColor = black!60, FillColor = black!60]

\begin{tikzpicture}[captiontext/.style={below=3mm, text width=5cm},rotate=90]

\Vertices[NoLabel]{circle}{A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14,A15,A16,A17,A18,A19,A20,A21,A22,A23,A24,A25,A26,A27,A28,A29,A30,A31,A32,A33,A34,A35} %the errors points this line
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document} 


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Off-topic: Don't load both amssymb and latexsym, and don't load both graphicx and graphics. In both cases, load just the first-named package. Next, no need to load amsfonts explicitly, as it 's loaded automatically by amssymb. You may also want to think about why you're loading both amscd and tikz-cd.

I can tell you why this happens, but not yet a fix. The tkz-berge package uses tkz-graph beneath the hood for the graph. And the code for Vertices in tkz-graph.sty has the line \global\expandafter\let\csname label@\alph{tkz@gr@p}\endcsname\liste}, with tkz@gr@p1 the counter for the vertices inserted. It is this call to \alph that gives an error when you add more than 26 vertices (as there are only 26 letters in the Latin alphabet).

It is a bit strange to me that the original package author choose to use \alph (which will run into this issue), and not just use the counter value directly, since the latter would avoid this issue. (It appears it may be just laziness? Later on in the code the author refers to \label@a explicitly, which if a number is used would require \csname label@0\endcsname instead. As I am not sure what this second part is doing, I am hesitant to craft a patch myself.)

I have sent an email to the maintainer of this package. I should also note that according to CTAN, the tkz-berge package should not be used since the package author (who is the same as the author as tkz-graph) is aware of some bugs with the code. So for the time being you may want to draw your graphs in a different way.

Thank you @WillieWong.
